# Payable Function Solidity - What is the error: The transaction has been reverted to the initial state

Tags: solidity, transactions, remix, ether, error

'm trying to make a simple transaction between two parts (Supplier and Producer). First I make the contract deploy, then I defined the amount (that will be 1) and I make the transaction ->[Amount transaction that works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGxPi.png) . Before I execute the payable function and I change the Remix account, defining 1 ether in the value. [Inputs for teh payable function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45uKe.png)

When I execute the payable function and the appears an error: [Transaction error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMGhF.png)

My code is below and I'm looking for an alternative to finalize the transaction between the two different accountS, any help is very welcome.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0; 

contract supply {

    address payable Supplier;
    address payable Producer;
    uint constant payment_unit = 1 ether;
    uint public price_feature1_wei = 0;
    string public features_product1;
    bool public SellSuplier = true;
    bool public contract_terminated = false;

    constructor () public payable {
        Supplier = msg.sender;
        features_product1 = "product description...";

    }

    function PriceFeature1 (uint amount) public {
        require (SellSuplier == true);
        require (Supplier == msg.sender);
        price_feature1_wei = amount * payment_unit;
    }

    function PurchaseFeature1() public payable {
        require (price_feature1_wei > 0);
        require (msg.value == price_feature1_wei);
        require (SellSuplier == true);
        require (Producer == msg.sender);
        require (Supplier.send(msg.value));
        SellSuplier = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set Producer, but checking:

```
require (Producer == msg.sender);
```

Obviously Producer not equal to msg.sender. And Solidity reverting it. It is better to using require with error messages like:

```
require (Producer == msg.sender, "You are not the Producer!");
```

So you can see where is the error.

Comment: Ok! When I try again, I see the error "You are not the producer". But how I set the Producer? I want to make this transaction with another account, that would be the Producer.

Comment: It is totally up to your strategy. But maybe you can take an address as a parameter on PriceFeature and then assign it to Producer.